# Chaining searching and sorting together in rails using serachlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, searchlogic

My code is very similar to that in [railscasts #240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

The differences are that I am using rails 2.3.10 so I am not using 'where'.  Instead I am using serachlogic and my model looks like this...

```
//Model.rb
def self.search(search)
      if search
        Model.column_name_like(search)
      else
        find(:all)
      end
    end
```

(I am using search logic because I need case insensitivity because I am deploying to heroku(postgres))

When I try and chain my methods together like in the railscast and in other tutorials I get an error such as "method order not found"

My controller is here...

```
 @objects=Model.search(params[:search]).order(sort_order('created_at'))
```

This is with a slightly different column sort method which was working for me before I stuck the search in.

Why does this method work in some tutorials but throwing an error in this case.  Is it because the tutorials are in rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

I found an optimal solution myself a few days later.  I had to make a change in my model. Instead of returning a find(:all) in the else I returned a new "empty"search object

```
@search=Model.column_name_like("")
```

Fore reference my model and controller which now supports sorting,searching, and pagination looks like...

```
def self.search(search)
      if search
        Model.column_name_like(search)
      else
        @search=Model.column_name_like("")
      end
    end

def index
  @per_page = params[:per_page] || Lease.per_page || 20
  @search=Lease.search(params[:search])
  @objects=@search.find(:all, :order=>(sort_column + " "+ sort_direction)).paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
end

private 
def sort_column
  Model.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "default_column_name"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

Don't forget to put hidden form helpers in your view to pass in the column name and direction.

```
<p>
<% form_tag leases_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<%=hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction]%>
<%=hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]%>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That railscast doesn't appear to be using searchlogic which explains why this is not working.  It is using rail3's new Active Record (Arel) libraries to accomplish a searchlogic-like behavior.

Instead of:

`@objects=Model.search(params[:search]).order(sort_order('created_at'))`

Try:

`@objects=Model.search(params[:search]).ascend_by_created_at`

Or:

`@objects=Model.search(params[:search]).descend_by_created_at`

cheers

Comment: That works but its not flexible enough.  I am currently using an application helper so I can sort by columns asc/dsc.  I also need to add pagination at the end so something like.. @objects.Model.search(params[:search]).order(sort_order('name')).paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])

Comment: instead of .descend_by_created_at or .ascend_by_created_at, you can pass it inside the params[:search] params.  so you can have params[:search][:order] = "ascend_by_created_at" or params[:search][:order] = "descend_by_created_at", this way you can have more control dynamically over things.